# gmmktime - one day off after converting with date() function

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm having a strange problem while trying to make a date from some user input using gmmktime(). It seems to always show my date as being one day behind when I convert it to a date for output. I have a date selection, and I am converting the date using the input from a month, year, and day drop down picker.

In my code, I have:

```
$inputDate = gmmktime(0,0,0,02,07,2012,0);
$inputDate = date("M d Y", $inputDate);
```

When this is output, the date that shows is Feb 06, 2012 instead of Feb 07, 2012. However if I change the gmmktime() to just mktime(), the date is correct and shows as the 7th.

Can someone explain why this is happening and what I need to do in order to use gmmktime() and have my dates displayed in the right format? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gmmktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) assumes that the entered date/time is GMT and automatically converts it to server time using date.timezone setting in php.ini. On my system which is +0500 GMT I get:

```
<?php
$inputDate = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 2012);
echo date("M d Y H:i:s O", $inputDate);
// Feb 07 2012 05:00:00 +0500
```

Notice that I passed `0, 0, 0` as the time to the function but ended up getting `05:00:00`. In your case it seems like your server is *behind* GMT so for every date you create using this function will be converted to -nnnn hours behind the specified date; for 00:00 GMT as the input this effectively means you get the previous date.

The workaround is simple, use [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) function to display dates created with `gmmktime()`:

```
<?php
$inputDate = gmmktime(0,0,0,2,7,2012);
echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s O", $inputDate);
// Feb 07 2012 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I ran that echo it spit out 'Feb 06 2012 19:00:00'. I just checked the time on the server and it is up to date for today, EST time. I checked the php.ini file as well and it's set to EST time as well. I don't quite understand what is going on here, this is my first time working with unix based server times.

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick. I'll have to talk to the systems people and see why the server is behind GMT. I just started at this new job so still getting up to speed with things. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: That explains it. EST is -05:00 GMT. So `gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 2012)` will give you `2012-02-06 19:00 EST` which is understandable and correct. See my revised answer.

Comment: ah that makes complete sense now that I think about it and have you explain it this way. I think I've got my head wrapped around these unix and server dates now, whew. Thanks again for thoughts!